# Why can't I get the result I got with the sklearn LogisticRegression with the coefficients_sgd method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iteration, gradient-descent

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

I used code below from  [How To Implement Logistic Regression From Scratch in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-logistic-regression-stochastic-gradient-descent-scratch-python/)

```
def predict(row, coefficients):
    yhat = coefficients[0]
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        yhat += coefficients[i + 1] * row[i]
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-yhat))

def coefficients_sgd(train, l_rate, n_epoch):
    coef = [0.0 for i in range(len(train[0]))]
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        sum_error = 0
        for row in train:
            yhat = predict(row, coef)
            error = row[-1] - yhat
            sum_error += error**2
            coef[0] = coef[0] + l_rate * error * yhat * (1.0 - yhat)
            for i in range(len(row)-1):
                coef[i + 1] = coef[i + 1] + l_rate * error * yhat * (1.0 - yhat) * row[i]
    return coef

dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0],
[1.465489372,2.362125076,0],
[3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
[1.38807019,1.850220317,0],
[3.06407232,3.005305973,0],
[7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
[5.332441248,2.088626775,1],
[6.922596716,1.77106367,1],
[8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
[7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]

l_rate = 0.3
n_epoch = 100
coef = coefficients_sgd(dataset, l_rate, n_epoch)
print(coef)
```

`[-0.39233141593823756, 1.4791536027917747, -2.316697087065274]`

```
x = np.array(dataset)[:,:2]
y = np.array(dataset)[:,2]
model = LogisticRegression(penalty="none")
model.fit(x,y)
print(model.intercept_.tolist() + model.coef_.ravel().tolist())
```

`[-3.233238244349982, 6.374828107647225, -9.631487530388092]`

What should I change to get the same or closer coefficients ? How can I establish initial coefficients , learning rate , n_epoch ?

Comment: Is your goal to get closer coefficients, or to have the same prediction accuracy?

Comment: Thanks for your time.I am only curious what the iterative process behind logistic regression.I am not interested in evaluation metrics like accuracy at this stage.

Comment: There are many different algorithms to determine the coefficients.  And each algorithm may have different update strategies/rates/steps and iteration stopping conditions.  I wouldn't expect different algorithms to necessarily stop with the same coefficients.

Answer (score 7):

Well, there are many nuances here

First, recall that estimating coefficients of logistic regression with (negative) log-likelihood is possible using various optimization methods, including SGD you implemented, but there is no exact, closed-form solution. So even if you implement an exact copy of scikit-learn's [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), you will need to set the same hyperparameters (number of epochs, learning rate, etc.) and random state to obtain the same coefficients.

Second, `LogisticRegression` offers five different optimization methods (`solver` parameter). You run `LogisticRegression(penalty="none")` with its default parameters and the default for `solver` is `'lbfgs'`, not SGD; so depending on your data and hyperparameters, you may get significantly different results.

> What should I change to get the same or closer coefficients ?

I would suggest comparing your implementation with [`SGDClassifier(loss='log')`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html?highlight=sgdclassifier#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) first, since `LogisticRegression` does not offer SGD solver. Although keep in mind that scikit-learn's implementation is more sophisticated, in particular having more hyperparameters for early stopping like `tol`.

> How can I establish initial coefficients, learning rate, n_epoch?

Typically, coefficients for SGD are initialized randomly (e.g., `uniform(-1/(2n), 1/(2n))`), using some data statistics (e.g., `dot(y, w)/(dot(w, w)` for every coefficient `w`), or with pre-trained model's parameters. On the contrary, there is no golden rule for learning rate or number of epochs. Usually, we set a big number of epochs and some other stopping criterion (e.g., whether norm between current and previous coefficients is smaller than some small `tol`), a moderate learning rate, and every iteration we reduce the learning rate following some rule (see `learning_rate` parameter of `SGDClassifier` or [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#id5)) and check the stopping criterion.